# Existence of commuting Chevalley involution

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetric-spaces

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple finite-dimensional complex Lie algebra, and let $\theta$ be a complex linear involution on $\mathfrak{g}$.  Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a Cartan subspace, and choose a $\theta$-stable Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ containing $\mathfrak{a}$.  Finally, make a choice of positive restricted roots in $\mathfrak{a}^*$, and extend this to a choice of positive roots in $\mathfrak{h}^*$, giving rise to a positive system for the roots of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Let $\omega$ denote the Chevalley involution of $\mathfrak{g}$ with respect to $\mathfrak{h}$ and the choice of positive system just described. To be explicit, $\omega$ is the unique automorphism of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $\omega(h)=-h$ for $h\in\mathfrak{h}$, and $\omega(e_{\pm\alpha})=e_{\mp\alpha}$ for all simple roots $\alpha$.

Is it true that $\omega$ commutes with $\theta$?

Comment: I think you have made a choice of pinning (choice of non-$0$ vector $e_\alpha$ in each root space for a simple root $\alpha$) that you are not mentioning; and then of course what you really mean is that $[e_\alpha, \omega(e_\alpha)]$ is the coroot $h_\alpha$, and $\omega^2(e_\alpha) = e_\alpha$.  (A different choice of pinning gives a different, though conjugate, Cartan involution, and this can affect commuting with $\theta$.)  This already forces $h_\alpha$ to be negated by $\omega$; so, since $\mathfrak g$ is simple, $\omega$ acts by negation on $\mathfrak h$—it's not a separate condition.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was being sloppy.  My statement wasn't meant to depend on the choice of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triples, although as we now see it's false anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realized that the answer is no.  I should have checked some examples!  The case of $(\mathfrak{gl}(4),\mathfrak{gl}(3)\times\mathfrak{gl}(1))$ gives a counterexample.  Indeed, this is induced by the involution $\theta$ given by conjugation by
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & i\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\-i &0 &0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$  Then $\theta$ preserves the Cartan subalgebra of diagonal matrices, which contains a Cartan subspace for this pair.  One choice of positive system compatible with the Iwasawa decomposition in this case is the usual one, giving the Borel of upper triangular matrices.  Thus a Chevalley involution $\omega$ is given by $X\mapsto-X^t$.

Now one can compute that $\omega\theta(e_{12})=-ie_{24}$ while $\theta\omega(e_{12})=ie_{24}$.

Comment: Isn't the centraliser of your involution $\operatorname{GL}_2 \times \operatorname{GL}_1^2$, embedded as $(g, s, t) \mapsto \frac1 2\begin{pmatrix} s + t & & & s - t \\ & 2g \\ t - s & & & s + t \end{pmatrix}$, not $\operatorname{GL}_3 \times \operatorname{GL}_1$?  Maybe I misunderstand the notation.  I think if you choose your Cartan subalgebra to be the diagonal inside $\operatorname{GL}_2$ times these two $\operatorname{GL}_1^2$'s, then things go better.

Comment: Namely, your involution is conjugate to $\operatorname{diag}(\zeta_8, 1, 1, -\zeta_8)$, where $\zeta_8$ is a primitive 8th root of unity, and it is clear that that automorphism behaves well with respect to the standard diagonal torus.

Comment: More generally, everything works fine for an inner automorphism (necessarily semisimple) if you choose a Cartan subalgebra corresponding to a torus containing the conjugating element, so you're fine there if you only worry about existence.  Then you need only worry about outer automorphisms.

Comment: I agree with your centralizer, but I was writing $\mathfrak{gl}(3)\times\mathfrak{gl}(1)$ for the fixed points of the involution. The involution is conjugate to $\operatorname{diag}(1,1,1,-1)$, but  the form I wrote it in above is one so that a Cartan subspace is contained in diagonal matrices.    Using $\operatorname{diag}(\zeta_8,1,1,-\zeta_8)$ by conjugation seems problematic because its square is not central?  So it doesn't seem to define an involution, no?  Also I don't follow your last argument, as I want the CSA to contain a Cartan subspace, so I don't want it to be fixed by $\theta$.

Comment: You are right about where the involution is conjugate; I don't know what I was thinking.  (I guess $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -i & 0 \end{pmatrix} \oplus I_2$ instead of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & i \\ -i & 0 \end{pmatrix} \oplus I_2$.)  I am not familiar with the term "Cartan subspace" (and it seems I just read it as "Cartan subalgebra"); is it a maximal Abelian subalgebra of the ($-1$)-eigenspace of $\theta$?

Comment: Also, I don't understand the difference between speaking of the centraliser of an involution and speaking of its fixed points.

Comment: Ah I see, yes so a Cartan subspace is a maximal toral subalgebra of the (-1)-eigenspace, (not just abelian).  Toral means all the elements are semisimple.  And then yeah I think when it comes to symmetric pairs, the centralizer of interest is that of the Cartan subspace.  So when I said centralizer I should have been more precise and said centralizer of the Cartan subspace.  The fixed points of the involution are just the fixed points in the usual sense.

Comment: Now that this question's back on the front page:  it seems to me that you answered your question, and have certainly given other people long enough to add any commentary of their own if they want, so that it is reasonable for you to accept your own answer.

Comment: Haha wait why is it on the front page?? okay I will accept my own answer, thanks!

Comment: [Questions without upvoted answers get periodically bumped to the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579).